# Format a string of text fields from a multi select table

Tags: crystal-reports, formatting, formula

So far here is What I have done:
replace({em_note3.orientation_ShVal},"&",ChrW(9))

And here is what I am getting in the preview screen:

&Person&Place&Time&Situation&

I want it to read:   Person, Place, Time, Situation

Can anyone help and tell me what I am doing wrong

Comment: Is it the full formula? If not, may you post the full formula? An tell us where did you use the formula.

Comment: how data is stored in `{em_note3.orientation_ShVal}` field